# Starting lighttpd from nagios renders lighttpd broken

Tags: nagios, lighttpd, sudo, start-stop-daemon

I'm using Debian 7.8 (wheezy), and lighttpd 1.4.31 with nagios 3.4.1.

when I start lighttpd normally (as root), everything works as expected:

```
/etc/init.d/lighttpd start
```

However, when nagios starts lighttpd, everything issues a 404 error, and nothing is logged to `/var/log/lighttpd/access.log` or `/var/log/lighttpd/error.log`.  I can mimic the same behavior manually by issuing the following command as root:

```
su - nagios -s /usr/bin/sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd start
```

The nagios daemon has sudo access, as defined in `/etc/sudoers.d/nagios`:

```
nagios ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/lighttpd *
```

What am I missing? What's the difference between starting lighttpd directly as root, and doing it as the nagios user via sudo?

Answer (score -1):

Is nagios _actually_using_ sudo when it's starting lighttpd ?

So, is it running 'sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd start', or is it running '/etc/init.d/lighttpd start'.

When not running from sudo... it won't run as root, and therefor won't work.

If in doubt... edit the /etc/init.d/lighttpd script, and let it print it's user in the beginning with something like:

id > /tmp/ligghtpd.start.$$

And then inspect the /tmp/ligghtpd.start.* files.

Comment: Yes, it's running from sudo. And the sudo command mentioned in the question accurately and reliably reproduces the observed behavior.